# Range Index not applied to field in eXist-DB (not shown in Monex)

Tags: xquery, exist-db

I am not sure, if this a bug or if I'm doing something wrong (or if I'm having the wrong assumptions).

I have a collection with one document:

```xml
<test bar="baz">foo</test>
```

And a `collection.xconf`:

```xml
<collection xmlns="http://exist-db.org/collection-config/1.0">
  <index xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <range>
      <create qname="test">
        <field name="bar-attr" match="@bar" type="xs:string"/>
        </create>
    </range>
  </index>
</collection>
```

Now i would assume, that the Index, when viewed in Monex, for `bar-attr`(in the index for the collection) lists the value of `@bar`(here `baz`). If I switch my configuration to:

```xml
<collection xmlns="http://exist-db.org/collection-config/1.0">
  <index xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <range>
      <create qname="@bar"/>
    </range>
  </index>
</collection>
```

`baz` is part of the index as expected.

Now my question:

1. Are field-values not listed in the index-view in monex?
2. Or is my understanding of the fields totally wrong?

Note: I am using eXist-db 6.2.0 in a Docker-Container on an Apple Silicon based Mac. But this problems seems also to exist in instances running outside Docker on other platforms (I can reproduce it in a Linux VM).

Comment: These are range index fields which I believe are deprecated or at least replaced by fields and facets created with the full text Lucene index - they all appear in Monex. https://exist-db.org/exist/apps/doc/lucene#facets-and-fields

Comment: You are right, there is an old range-index. But I'm using the new one. I don't want to perform a fulltext search – that's what the lucene index is for as far as I know – but want to use the index for simple queries.

Comment: Ok i found the corresponding issues in GitHub:
1. https://github.com/eXist-db/monex/issues/191
2. https://github.com/eXist-db/exist/issues/4074 

So everything is fine – it's just a bug in Monex. You can still view the index using `range:index-keys-for-field`

Comment: Glad you found Ash's issue and a workaround. Hopefully we'll get to the bottom of it.